# How could I make vampires realistically weak to sunlight?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, vampires

I’m currently developing lore for a story that I may one day write. A space opera where creatures such as vampires, werewolves, and zombies exist.

Before I ask my question, I would like to tell you a little bit about my vampires. Since this is a science fiction setting, they don’t have any supernatural abilities, though they are immortal and physically superior to ordinary humans. They also aren’t undead, nor are they created by a virus, but are instead artificially created mutants, capable of infecting others using a form of venom.

Like most vampires, they are weak to sunlight, which blisters their skin and can kill them within minutes if they don’t find shelter. My question is, how could I explain their weakness to sunlight in a realistic manner? I know that there are animals in real life that dislike sunlight, but it isn’t fatal to them.

Comment: There are photo-sensitive chemicals out there. Find one and make it critical for their biology and have it need to do it's job near the surface of their skin.

Comment: "are instead artificially created mutants"
This is the problem.
There is 0 point in realistic useful creation of a creature that is destroyed by sunlight. I just don't see it.
Now a failure in the process, Powerpuff Girls style, or something might explain it.
But again with sufficient technology you will correct it at least in the newer generations.
The only way is trying too hard.
Failure in the creation process+losing the ability to make new vampires like how in Warhammer 40K everything is kinda lost.
Seems odd anyway to have such good tech an have your vampire die from the sun

Comment: @Seallussus unless the weakness was built by design. It's also possible that the tech is imperfect and can only produce, say "immortality" when coupled with the gene for "weakness for sunlight". Or whatever combination you want where one is a trait you want the weakness is the other. Or similar - point being that *at the time* of creating the vampires, it couldn't be done without the sunlight weakness. It's entirely possible that's being worked on in-universe - no point in assuming some technology is perfect in order to produce something useful.

Comment: @VLAZ,
Seems like a total nonsense to me.
How on earth can you produce immortality, yep immortality, and not be able to handle such an obvious and huge problem?
If in your setting you can make artificially immortal beings then I simply have to assume that the weakness to the sun is either a plot-hole or you want to have your cake and eat it too.
Frame challenges are allowed here btw.

Comment: @Seallussus    
The technology used to create them in the first place has been lost for almost a thousand years. They can only reproduce by infecting people with a form of toxin they produce using an organ in their mouth.

Comment: @DaikyuMaryu,
So the latter part of my comment?
Anyway it good to see that you at least hand waved the thing.

Comment: @Seallussus I’ve decided that it was a genetic weakness purposely placed within them when they were created, one not even their brightest scientists can fix. All attempts to do so have been catastrophic failures.

Answer (score 6):

They're very, very, allergic to light.

[Solar urticaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_urticaria) is a light-triggered [phototoxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototoxicity) allergic reaction that can cause swelling, difficulty breathing, red itchy rashes, blistering and a burning sensation. This is rather mild, but there are far more extreme photosensitivity reactions connected to [phytophotodermatitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytophotodermatitis), such as those triggered by the sap of the [giant hogweed (*heracleum mantegazzianum*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_mantegazzianum): blindness, third-degree burns, much worse rashes.

*Rarely* reactions can include bronchial constriction and anaphylactic reactions, but at that stage death is not merely possible, it's plausible.

So your vampires are violently allergic to light – visible or specifically ultraviolet – due to abnormal (for human) allergic sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

**PORPHYRIA:**

Porphyria is a disorder that is often associated with vampirism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria **and** https://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/vampirelike-symptoms-occur-hereditary-porphyria.php You don't die in minutes when exposed to light, but it does result in extreme sensitivity to light. There are a myriad of symptoms, any and all of which can be selected to give your vampires whatever odd illnesses or behaviors you like.Sunlight burns, and prolonged exposure causes blisters and skin lesions. It is a disorder of heme (yes, as in blood) and people often need blood (transfusions) to compensate for the illness. Some forms can cause teeth to turn red and glow in ultraviolet light, a lurid effect and very vampiric. Garlic has compounds that can aggravate the symptoms of porphyria. Their urine turns purple when exposed to light, a color traditionally deemed royal.

So how do you make this apply to your vampires? They are immortal. Some pretty severe changes need to happen to humans to make them live forever, and these changes can have corresponding metabolic consequences. Vampirism can be a form of porphyria. Perhaps the vampiric porphyrins break down to a deadly neurotoxin in the presence of certain wavelengths of light. More than a few minutes of exposure could cause your vampire to need to be rushed to the emergency room.

Or maybe it's not really lethal, but some of the symptoms of an acute attack of porphyria are convulsions, anxiety, confusion, psychosis and hallucinations. Imagine your vampire believing he's dying and acting like it. If you're making them extra-strong, a freaked out berserker in pain is pretty terrifying, and might get killed by authorities.

Comment: L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica♦ was answering this while I was composing my answer, and included porphyria. I think my answer covers this in greater detail, so I'm letting it stand, but he gets credit for saying it first.

Answer (score 2):

I myself am rather sensitive to sunlight, have had several skin cancers removed, and have to visit a skin doctor periodically to check for skin cancer and precancer.  I also take blood pressure pills which have the side effect of increasing sensitivity to sunlight.  But the fastest that sunlight harms me is that it sometimes caused my skin to burn, turn red, and peel off after a day or two at the beach, which I now avoid.

But it would take years or decades for sun exposure to kill me with skin cancer that wasn't treated.

So I am sympathetic to characters who find sunlight painful or unhealthy.

I find it easy to believe that plausible beings, such as aliens from a star which emits less ultra violent ultraviolet light, or your realistic "vampires", would suffer from sunlight exposure.

What is hard to believe in is realistic beings that would die within minutes from exposure to sunlight at sea level on Earth, where they are protected from ultraviolet by ozone layer.

So possibly in your story the ozone layer has been weakened - perhaps by a gamma ray burst -and the surface of the earth thus gets much more ultraviolet light than it used to.  People, animals, and plants now suffer a lot from ultraviolet light, so if your "vampires" have weakness to ultraviolet light, such as porphyria and/or solar urticaria, possibly exposure to bright noontime sunlight would kill them within hours or even minutes, while exposure to weaker sunlight would take much longer to kill them.

You might want to research the effects of intense sunlight on albinos and se how that compares to the effects you desire for your "vampires".

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation could be [porphyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria#Vampires_and_werewolves)

> Porphyria has been suggested as an explanation for the origin of vampire and werewolf legends, based upon certain perceived similarities between the condition and the folklore.

> In January 1964, L. Illis's 1963 paper, "On Porphyria and the Aetiology of Werewolves," was published in Proceedings of the Royal Society of Medicine. Later, Nancy Garden argued for a connection between porphyria and the vampire belief in her 1973 book, Vampires. In 1985, biochemist David Dolphin's paper for the American Association for the Advancement of Science, "Porphyria, Vampires, and Werewolves: The Aetiology of European Metamorphosis Legends," gained widespread media coverage, popularizing the idea.

Another option might be some plant sap, like [giant hogweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_mantegazzianum#Public_health_and_safety), that they smear on their skin for some other purpose.

> The sap of the giant hogweed plant is phototoxic. Contact with the plant sap prevents the skin from being able to protect itself from sunlight, which leads to phytophotodermatitis, a serious skin inflammation